# Eclipse errors on Composer "vendor" folder

Tags: php, eclipse, composer-php, phpmailer, eclipse-pdt

I have tried anything I can think of, Google, different flags, to understand why is my Eclipse (version Oxygen.2 Release [4.7.2] with PDT) installation giving errors as soon as I install a project via *Composer* onto my PHP project.

Currently trying to add `composer require phpmailer/phpmailer` but I get the following errors. Tried doing it via `composer install --no-dev` but still get the errors.

[image: Eclipse errors screenshot]

The same has happened with several other *Composer* installed projects like

Anybody has encountered the same "problem"? Should I ignore those errors and just continue coding/deploying? Or is it really missing these Classes and it will crash on the site? I thought *Composer* handled every include for you.

*Same problem with `composer require kunalvarma05/dropbox-php-sdk`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Those errors are all in the scripts that support XOAUTH2 which make use of *optional* dependencies which you don't have installed. They are not included by default, but if you look in the `composer.json` file you'll see they are suggested packages.

These errors are harmless if you're not using XOAUTH2.

Comment: Thanks! I figure it might be related to that since `composer suggest` gave me some suggestions but I've had the problem that no matter how much suggestions I keep adding the error either continue or keep piling up. Is there a way to do some kind of "recursive" require in _Composer_ in order to have "everything" needed?

Comment: I’d recommend you tell your IDE to ignore those files since you’re not using them. Generally you should not have syntax checks being applied to dependencies, only your own code. Composer does do recursive require, but only based on what is required by composer.json; it’s not about to start parsing source files.